# Can Momentum of an object change without net acceleration on the object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum

Comfy with single variable calculus and basic concepts of classical mechanics.

Comment: If you change the momentum you have changed the velocity. If you have changed the velocity there must have been an acceleration.

Comment: Not necessary. I never said the mass needs to be constant.This much I could figure out lol.

Comment: Please explain how this point like object changes mass.

Comment: I dont know.I did not think this through very much.Sorry.But remove the 'point like' condition and the question still holds.

Comment: To those who have flagged the question as unclear,I was looking for a mathematical answer and Not for a specific example.

Comment: But mass is taken to be constant, even in Special Relativity, so mass cannot 'change' unless you're talking about a special circumstance ( you didn't mention,  if you are..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition: the momentum is $\boldsymbol{P}=m\boldsymbol{v}$ where $m$ is the mass and $\boldsymbol{v}$ the velocity. By Newton's second law of motion:
$$\boldsymbol{F}=\frac{d\boldsymbol{P}}{dt}=m\frac{d\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}+\frac{dm}{dt}\boldsymbol{v}$$
By defining the acceleration $\boldsymbol{a}=\frac{d\boldsymbol{v}}{dt}$, if we set $\boldsymbol{a}=0$ we can still have:
$$\frac{d\boldsymbol{P}}{dt}=\frac{dm}{dt}\boldsymbol{v}$$

which could be non zero.
Thus the answer is YES: net momentum can change without acceleration if the mass $m$ of the object changes with time.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the answers to **variable mass" problems  using this site's search engine. The answer that you have given is at variance to other answers on this site.